# 佢 read "jì" from Hakka?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

Looking through the book *四川德阳方言语音演化与接触研究*, I came across the following chart excerpt:

> 表1-6 四川境内非西南官话方言岛与湖广方言特征词对比
>
> [image]

In some locales 他 is documented as being read: 佢, tɕi⁵¹ -or- jì, if you prefer.

Places of influence are limited to either:

> 老湖广话

or

> 或客家话方言岛

Xiang, Cantonese or Hakka.

[Hakka](https://hakkadict.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/gs32/gsweb.cgi/ccd=lRaNKD/record?r1=5&h1=0&recordlinkid=HK0000003700) seems to be the most likely, but the readings are all closer to:

> gi

rather than ji.

Are there Hakka topolects that read 佢 as [tɕi]? Or perhaps Cantonese topolects? Xiang is not very likely I'm guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are Hakka varieties that have palatalised 佢 and other former velars in front of front vowels, specifically in various Hakka varieties of Jiangxi and Hunan (寧龍片, 于信片/雩桂片 and 銅鼓片/銅桂片).

Without context, it is rather difficult to determine the *tone category* of the phonetic "51". But I shall assume it is a 陽平 tone.

A list of pronunciations for `渠` in a greater range of Hakka varieties can be found at [zdic.net](https://www.zdic.net/zd/yy/ky/%E6%B8%A0) (where it also specifies that it is equivalent to Modern Standard Mandarin 他 for some varieties). I could not however find /tɕi51/ on the list, although there are several /tɕi24/ (陰平 tone, characteristic of 銅桂片).